# From wide to long format with Date variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below

```
begin = c('01.01.2015',  '01.03.2015')
event = c('01.06.2015',  NA)
end = c('01.07.2015',  '01.12.2015')
fact1 = c('a', 'b')
fact2 = c('d', 'c')
df = as.data.frame(cbind(begin, event, end, fact1, fact2))

df[, c('begin', 'event', 'end')] <- lapply(df[, c('begin', 'event', 'end')], as.Date, format="%d.%m.%Y")
df[, c('begin', 'event', 'end')] <- lapply(df[, c('begin', 'event', 'end')], as.Date, origin="1970-01-01")
df


 begin        event        end       fact1 fact2
1 2015-01-01 2015-06-01 2015-07-01     a     d
2 2015-03-01       <NA> 2015-12-01     b     c
```

I want to get a dataframe like this

```
     begin       end      fact1 fact2
1 2015-01-01  2015-06-01     NA    d
1 2015-06-01  2015-07-01     a     d
2 2015-03-01  2015-12-01     b     c
```

In rows where `event = NA` is no changes.

In row where `event` is Date I need to add a new row and `event` becomes `begin` in this new row. In the 'old' row `event` becomes `end`.

In addition, some of the variables remain unchanged (fact2),  and some change: the `fact1` belongs to what happened after `event`
I tried to solve this task with `reshape2` иut nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option.  Create an index of non-NA 'event' ('i1').  Then replicate the rows of 'df' using that index, specifying the `i` (`!is.na(event) & !duplicated(event)`), assign the 'end' and 'fact1' to 'event' and NA respectively.  Then assign the 'begin' to `shift`ed 'end' where there is `duplicated` 'begin'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- !is.na(df$event)
setDT(df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), i1+1),])[!is.na(event) & !duplicated(event), 
     c('end', 'fact1') := .(event, NA)][, event := NULL
   ][, end1 := shift(end)][duplicated(begin), begin := end1
    ][, end1 := NULL][]
#        begin        end fact1 fact2
#1: 2015-01-01 2015-06-01    NA     d
#2: 2015-06-01 2015-07-01     a     d
#3: 2015-03-01 2015-12-01     b     c
```